# sphinxsearch Delta index updates

Tags: sphinx, delta-index

I have a problem with Delta-index updates.
If the document id is less than the `max_doc_id`, is not included in the delta-index, so as long as main-index is not updated, the changes will not apply this data.
Suppose, we have 1000 data.
If fiftieth document is changed, there will be no changes in the delta-index.
How will delta-index include documents changes that their id is less than `max_doc_id`?
Is there a way that delta-index includes the data are updated so that we do not have to wait main-index run?

```
CREATE TABLE sph_counter
(
    counter_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    max_doc_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
source main
{
    # ...
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 1, MAX(id) FROM documents
    sql_query = SELECT id, title, body FROM documents \
     WHERE id<=( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
}

source delta : main
{
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query = SELECT id, title, body FROM documents \
     WHERE id>( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A really simply way I like for this is just to add a timestamp column to **automatically** track changed documents.

Add a column...

```
ALTER TABLE documents 
   ADD updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   INDEX(updated);
```

The default is also important, so it newly created documents are *also* included.

Then can just use that in queries, with a kill list. The main will include include all documents at time of indexing. But the delta will include new and changed documents. The kill list means the **old** version in main, is ignored.

```
CREATE TABLE sph_counter
(
    counter_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    max_doc_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    indexing_time DATETIME NOT NULL
);
source main
{
    # ...
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 1, MAX(id), NOW() FROM documents
    sql_query = SELECT id, title, body FROM documents
}

source delta : main
{
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8

    sql_query = SELECT id, title, body FROM documents \
     WHERE updated > ( SELECT indexing_time FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )

    sql_query_killlist = SELECT id FROM documents \
     WHERE updated > ( SELECT indexing_time FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
}
```

(as have the kill list, no point filtering the main, duplicates wont matter. Also dont neve need max_doc_id - so sph_counter could be simplified along with the sql_query_pre. In many way its a shame you have to repeat the query in the kill list. Can't just tell sphinx to use all the docs in the index as a kill list)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track document updates along with insertions, you should have a separate column for a document revision. Revision values should be unique across the document table, so it's a good idea to use global sequence to generate them.

When you update an existing document or insert a new one, you should take the next value from the revision sequence and save it in the document revision column. Sometimes it's a good idea to have DB triggers for automatic revision updates.

Then in `sql_query_pre` section you can save min and max revision values into `sph_counter` table and use them to create a proper delta index.

Comment: Well its very similar to using a timestamp, just maintaining a incrementing sequence explicitly. Every time you update a document woudl explicity update the revision. Same result - would have a way of finding which documents HAVE changed. Either would work